# IntelliJ spring-boot-devtools not detecting changes automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

**I want to enable automatic restarting/reloading using spring-boot-devtools in Intellij community edition**

I have it listed in the Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I have console messages to indicate that the devtools have been initialised correctly, such as the live reload server being started.

However when I make changes to a Java class or a static file in the resources directory, it never causes a restart/reload.

I can *manually* invoke a restart/reload by using `Build > Build Project` , but I really need this to be an automatic thing as I am mainly working on a separate window in VSCode (working on JavaScript files, which the community version of IntelliJ doesn't support)

I have tried the following two settings which seemed to be the solution to this or similar issues:

- Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Build project automatically
- Settings > Advanced Settings > Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running
- Ensuring that restarting is enabled with "`devtools: restart: enabled: true` " in the application.yml
- Reloading maven dependencies
- Reinstalling IntelliJ

But I am still unable to get the restarts to happen automatically.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-233.13135.103, built on December 20, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 11448M
Cores: 24
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  Statistic (4.2.14)
  Lombook Plugin (233.13135.65)
  izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2024.1.0-233)
  org.sonarlint.idea (10.2.1.77304)
Kotlin: 233.13135.103-IJ
```

**Update:**
I've found that automatic restart/reload works, but I have to focus the IntelliJ window after making changes in VSCode. Any way to allow IntelliJ to check for changes while window is not focussed?

Comment: Automatic compilation doesn't work while application is running or debugging. It is written next to the corresponding check box in the Settings dialog. Please try to set "Update" action for your configuration.

Comment: @y.bedrov I tried those settings as it was suggested in other threads as a fix for this issue.

The docs for devtools says "Applications that use spring-boot-devtools will automatically restart whenever files on the classpath change." "By default changing resources in /META-INF/maven, /META-INF/resources, /resources, /static, /public or /templates will not trigger a restart but will trigger a live reload"

https://github.com/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets/blob/2020.3/README.md#yaml

Can you confirm what you mean by "Update" action, I don't see this option in my app's run config

Comment: I meant this option: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#application-update-policies

Comment: @y.bedrov Unfortunately Spring Boot-specific options are not present in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get automatic restart/reload working by enabling the following two options:

- `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Build project automatically`
- `Settings > Advanced Settings > Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running`

I was not able to get IntelliJ to *detect* changes while not focussed on the window, however I did find that enabling the following option can work almost as well:

- `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Sync external changes: Periodically when the IDE is inactive (experimental)`

I presume this is reloading the files from disk at an interval, similar to `File > Reload All From Disk` however it seems the interval is quite short, so most of the time is not noticeable.